# Qual a maneira correta/user friendly de realizar essa operação?

Tags: android, android-layout, ux

Normalmente em aplicações desktop/web, temos um campo `código` onde é inserido o código de algo e ao lado outro campo que mostra a descrição desse "algo" após a busca no banco.

Essa operação de buscar o item relacionado no banco normalmente ocorre quando o campo de texto `codigo` perde seu foco, após um tab por exemplo. Muitas vezes há também, um botão de busca, caso o usuário não saiba o código. Até aí tudo bem.

Minha dúvida é relacionada a dispositivos móveis, pois utilizando essa aproximação que mencionei anteriormente, fica realmente estranho. Além do usuário ter que clicar em outra coisa para o `EditText` perder o foco, não fica intuitivo e claro para ele que é assim que funciona, fora que o teclado ficará aberto podendo tapar o campo da descrição, etc.

Pensei em abrir um `Dialog` quando o campo `codigo` receber o foco para o usuário inserir o número e dar OK, mas e se caso ele não saiba o código? Ou talvez um `Dialog` com a lista de itens ou até outra `activity`, mas se eu tiver mais de 1000 itens complica. Alguém tem uma dica ou ideia melhor?

Ex. que eu **não** gostaria de utilizar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pergunta interessante. As aproximações que envolvam perda de foco funcionam bem na web e no desktop, já no mobile, como usuário, eu desaprovo. O que acha do tratamento no "Ok" do teclado do sistema, como é feito nos campos de busca? Um exemplo é a pesquisa da Play Store.

Comment: Entendo, é uma boa ideia, mas como é por código ainda é estranho, além disso o usuário pode optar por simplesmente minimizar o teclado após escrever o código. Acredito que talvez a melhor maneira seja não tratar por código e sim pela descrição, abrindo uma lista após a inserção de 1 caractere para limitar a busca no banco... Mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: Quem negativou poderia explicar no que posso melhorar a pergunta?